# How can loosely typed language have constant lookup time for an array?

Tags: python, c, arrays

If I have an integer array "arr" of length 10 in C, to look up arr[5] the program can simply add 20 to the current pointer location and retrieve my value (constant time).

But if the array is loosely typed(python/javascript list) how can the pointer know in constant time where an element is? Since it can no longer assume that each element is fixed bytes.

Comment: You're correct in that we cant rely on data offset for constant lookup. Often different data structures such as hash tables or trees are implemented in order to preserve amortized constant time

Comment: If you have a "generic object" type, that could be an array of bytes or equivalent. At a fixed location in that array can be info about size, members, etc. And an array is an object, so it would tell you what kind of things it contained and what size they were and have a pointer to where the "real" array starts in memory. Basically think of an array as a C array nested *inside* a regular object. Or something like that, this is just a rough idea.

Comment: It could keep an internal list of pointers, which are a constant size.

Comment: The actual underlying array that backs a Python list is a constant sized array of PyObject pointers.

Comment: Thank you! that's very helpful to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check Python's source code - [listobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1a5856bf9295fa73995898d576e0bedf016aee1f/Include/listobject.h):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

We can see here that Python's `list` is just an array of pointers to `PyObject`. So to access 5th element we simply need to take `ob_item[5]` which will just add 20 (40) to the value of pointer `ob_item`.

You can see the actual code in [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8017b804a06804793bcc0a7f734d8a846b0fe18a/Objects/listobject.c):

```
static PyObject *
list_item(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    ...
    Py_INCREF(a->ob_item[i]);
    return a->ob_item[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's extremely helpful